# How to add tags with comma as separator in jquery method?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, leaflet

json returns an array of tags with this structure :

`'FOOTBALL','BASKET','TENNIS'`

I need to put this tag list with the comma as a separator and the quotes around the tags
So I use this function to turn my array into a string :

`var test = data.tag_sport.join();`

the test variable displays well :

`'FOOTBALL','BASKET','TENNIS'`

But when I put this variable in the jquery method (this is fonction leaflet to add marker on a map ... ) it does not work :

`L.marker([data.lat, data.lng],{tags:[test]}).addTo(macarte);`

On the other hand if I put the list of tags in the hard method it works correctly

`L.marker([data.lat, data.lng],{tags:['FOOTBALL','BASKET','TENNIS']}).addTo(macarte);`

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass comma to [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) array method like:

```
var test = data.tag_sport.join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = ['FOOTBALL','BASKET','TENNIS'];
L.marker([data.lat, data.lng],{tags:test}).addTo(macarte);
```

Place your array in test variable and pass it to marker function if it accept array. You don't need to join the array with commas.

And if you need to add commas, then use:

```
var test = data.tag_sport.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tag_sport array then don't need to use Join. Use directly like below.

`L.marker([data.lat, data.lng],{tags:data.tag_sport}).addTo(macarte);`

if tag_sport is comma saperated , You need to split using comma . see below

`L.marker([data.lat, data.lng],{tags:data.tag_sport.split(',')}).addTo(macarte);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for yours answers, but it must be a big mystery because when I put it:

`var test = ['FOOTBALL','BASKET','TENNIS'];
L.marker([data.lat, data.lng],{tags:test}).addTo(macarte);`

it works.But as soon as I put something back by json in the test variable, it does not work :(